# SQL aggregation function from two related tables return multiplied results

Tags: sql, oracle

I have three tables and I get a wrong result when making some
aggregation SQL queries.

**Table 1:**

> ```
> id->pk,
> field1 -> INT
> ```

**Table 2:**

> ```
> id->pk,
> field1-> INT,
> tbl1_id-> fk to table 1 id,
> ```

**Table 3:**

> ```
> id->pk,
> field1-> INT,
> tbl1_id-> fk to table 1 id,
> ```

SQL:

```
Select t1.id,
       sum(t2.field),
       sum(t3.field)
from   table1 t1,
       table2 t2,
       table3 t3
where  t1.id=t2.id
and    t1.id=t3.id
group by t1.id
```

A solution that I found on googling stackoverflow is to use a distinct:

```sql
Select t1.id,sum(DISTINCT t2.field1), sum(DISTINCT t3.field1)
```

But am not sure that's a working solution for all other sql functions (avg, count, ... )

Returned result is wrong and I need some help, I don't know what I am missing.

Comment: Please share your sample data and expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Using `distinct` is not correct, because you might have duplicate values in either of the tables.

A safer approach is to use correlated subqueries:

```
Select t1.id,
       (select sum(t2.field)
        from table2 t2
        where t1.id = t2.id
       ),
       (select sum(t3.field)
        from table3 t3
        where t1.id = t3.id
       )
from table1 t1;
```

Note:  This is slightly different from your version because it includes all rows from `table1`, rather than all rows that match both `table2` and `table3`.  I'm guessing this is a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you have some problem with the join column names. For example in your table description you mentioned that `tbl1_id` column is foreign key for table2 and table3. But you joined these tables with id columns of each other

```
 where  t1.id=t2.id
 and    t1.id=t3.id
```

If you want to join these tables, from what you have written, you need to join foreign keys to the primary key:

```
Select t1.id,
       sum(t2.field),
       sum(t3.field)
from   table1 t1,
       table2 t2,
       table3 t3
where  t1.id=t2.tbl1_id 
and    t1.id=t3.tbl1_id 
group by t1.id
```

But if your foreign key is ID, then, you should left join these tables and in case you have null values four your fields, you should use `NVL`.

> NVL` will replace null with 0.

```
SELECT t1.id, 
       SUM (NVL (t2.field, 0)),
       SUM (NVL (t3.field, 0))
  FROM table1 t1, table2 t2, table3 t3
   WHERE t1.id = t2.id(+) 
   AND t1.id = t3.id(+)
  GROUP BY t1.id
```